# How does scanf work with both strings and integers? C

Tags: c, string, linked-list, scanf, strcmp

So I have a program that takes a data string and a number on the end that is it's position in the priority that it's to be printed out. I'm required to use linked list's and I've figured out how to do so with that, however the way this program is executed is at the end of the data strings and priority's the user is supposed to enter NONE and the program executes. The problem is that my check with strcmp is forcing the user to enter NONE twice to execute the program. I don't think I'm using the scanf for string and int values correctly and that's where my problem lies but I'm not sure.

Here's a correct sample input:

```
andk81739wewe 7

qweod125632ao 3

lenlc93012wasd 0

093deaeiao12 5

13jadacas291 3

...


NONE
```

Here's what actually has to be typed for the program to execute

```
andk81739wewe 7

qweod125632ao 3

lenlc93012wasd 0

093deaeiao12 5

13jadacas291 3

...

NONE

NONE
```

Any ideas as to why a second NONE has to be typed for the program to recognize that none has been typed?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LARGE 100

struct node
{
    char data[LARGE];
    int position;
    struct node* next;
};


void sortedInsert(struct node** first, struct node* new_node)
{
    struct node* current;
    if (*first == NULL || (*first)->position <= new_node->position)
    {
        new_node->next = *first;
        *first = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        current = *first;
        while (current->next!=NULL &&
               current->next->position > new_node->position)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        new_node->next = current->next;
        current->next = new_node;
    }
}


struct node *newNode(char *new_data,int position)
{
    struct node* new_node =
    (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    strcpy(new_node->data,new_data);
    new_node->position=position;
    new_node->next =  NULL;

    return new_node;
}

void printList(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s  \n", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main(void) {

    char job[LARGE],blank[1]={' '},*p,*q;
    int number=0,x=0;
    q=&blank[1];
    struct node* first = NULL;
    struct node *new_node = newNode(q,0);
    printf("Please enter printing jobs\n");
    while(x!=1){
        if(strcmp(job,"NONE")==0){
            x=1;
        }
        else{
            scanf("%s", job);
            scanf("%d", &number);
            p=&job[0];
            sortedInsert(&first, new_node);
            new_node = newNode(p,number);
        }
    }
    printf("Print Job in order from 9-0\n");
    printList(first);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to check the `strcmp` after the first `scanf` and before the second `scanf`. Otherwise it reads "NONE" and then tries to read an int. The int `scanf` only returns (and fails) when you enter something else (the second NONE). There are other problems with your code. For example, `job` is uninitialised the first time `strcmp` is called. Also, you should always check the return value of `scanf` and make sure that it does not overflow the `job` buffer.

Comment: Thanks @kaylum for the tips! So should I always initalize every single variable when I create it instead of leaving it just the way I have it?

Comment: @Senglish. You should initialize variable before you use it. Otherwise, you will get undefined behaviour.

Comment: But if I'm only looking for one thing and I know my input to be predefined, ie I already have what is being tested of my program, is it still in my interest to predetermine what these variables hold as good programming practice or is sort of like a grammar natzi thing, not to be rude or anything, I'm just curious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you may use following code segment. This one is more reduced and simplified approach.:

```
 int main(void) {

    char job[LARGE];
    struct node *first = NULL;
    struct node *new_node = NULL;
    int number;
    printf("Please enter printing jobs\n");
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%s", job);
        if(!strcmp(job, "NONE"))
            break;
        scanf("%d", &number);

        new_node = newNode(job, number);

        sortedInsert(&first, new_node);
    }

    printf("Print Job in order from 9-0\n");
    printList(first);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This solution causes a problem if there is two inputs with the same precedence. It will print the first one given by the user and not the other, for instance if I do two data strings with the precedence of 3 are given, only one of them will be printed.

Comment: @Senglish, I don't get what you mean by precedence.

Comment: so in the input part in my original post each data string inputed has a number at the end that tells the precedence in which data string should be printed out. If one of these like in my example has the same precedence, then only of them is printed, not both.

Comment: @Senglish. I have updated my answer. Now I hope, it will work as you expect.

Comment: that worked, Thank you very much! Could you explain why changing the first and new_node being changed to NULL fixed the problem of not recording the last data string coming in?

Comment: In your original code, you were initially creating a node with `precedence` 0, and then after reading first set of inputs you were inserting node created initially. In general, you were inserting node created in `ith` iteration in (i+1)th iteration. Since there is no call to insert function after you provide `END` as input, last record will not added to list.